# Binding issue in Angular of object properties

Tags: angular

I have this component in my application that have an object:

```
  boWizard: BoWizardFull = {
    wizard: {
      id: null,
      userId: null,
      currentWizardStep: this.currentStep,
      completed: false,
      creationDate: null,
      updatedOn: null,
      boFutureAptId: null,
      boFutureAptInvId: null,
      boFutureAvgInvId: null,
      boFutureGoalId: null,
      boFutureKeepAptId: null,
      boPrevInvestmentId: null,
      boProductMixId: null,
      boWizardReviewId: null,
      boFutureApt: null,
      boFutureAptInv: null,
      boFutureAvgInv: null,
      boFutureGoal: null,
      boFutureKeepApt: null,
      boPrevInvestment: null,
      boProductMix: null,
      boWizardReview: null
    },
    currentProductMix: null,
    plannedProductMix: null
  };
```

This object have multiple small objects as port of like: `boPrevInvestment: null` etc. So the thing is that this object is being modified multiple times during the life of this component and I have binding to a few child components:

```
<div class="wizard__pages">
            <lib-wizard-intro #introSave *ngIf="currentStep === 1" (boWizardSave)="handleSaveRequest($event)" [bowizard]="boWizard" (nextPage)="nextStep($event)" (closePage)="fireClose()"></lib-wizard-intro>
            <lib-wizard-focusoverview #focusOverviewSave *ngIf="currentStep === 2" (boWizardSave)="handleSaveRequest($event)" [bowizard]="boWizard" (nextPage)="nextStep($event)" (prevPage)="prevStep()" (closePage)="fireClose()"></lib-wizard-focusoverview>
            <lib-wizard-introannualgoals #introAnnualGoalsSave *ngIf="currentStep === 3" (boWizardSave)="handleSaveRequest($event)"  [bowizard]="boWizard" (nextPage)="nextStep($event)" (prevPage)="prevStep()" (closePage)="fireClose()"></lib-wizard-introannualgoals>
            <lib-wizard-screenfour #screenFourSave *ngIf="currentStep === 4" [canContinue]="screenFourCanContinue" [boPrevInvestment]="boWizard.wizard.boPrevInvestment" (boWizardSave)="handleSaveRequest($event)" [bowizard]="boWizard" (nextPage)="nextStep($event)" (prevPage)="prevStep()" (closePage)="fireClose()"></lib-wizard-screenfour>
...
```

The problem is that when I update this object for example subscribing from an http requests the child components doesn't received the notification and the change of the values.
For example: I have this binding:
`[boPrevInvestment]="boWizard.wizard.boPrevInvestment"`
And I have this method:

```
getDataFromDV3() {
    const self = this;
    this.previousInvestmentSubscription = forkJoin(
      self.lastYearService.getInvDollarAndTransGdc(self.userId),
      self.lastYearService.getAverageCommission(self.userId),
      self.lastYearService.getAssetsUnderManagement(self.userId),
      self.lastYearService.getRecurringRevenue(self.userId),
      self.lastYearService.getNonAnnuityInsGdc(self.userId),
      self.lastYearService.getTotalGdc(self.userId)
    ).subscribe( results => {
      self.boWizard.wizard.boPrevInvestment.transactionalGDC = results[0].transactionalGDC;
      self.boWizard.wizard.boPrevInvestment.investedDollar = results[0].investedDollar;
      self.boWizard.wizard.boPrevInvestment.averageCommission = results[1].averageCommission;
      self.boWizard.wizard.boPrevInvestment.aum = results[2].aum;
      self.boWizard.wizard.boPrevInvestment.recurringRevenue = results[3].recurringRevenue;
      self.boWizard.wizard.boPrevInvestment.nonAnnuityInsuranceGdc = results[4].nonAnnuityInsuranceGdc;
      self.boWizard.wizard.boPrevInvestment.totalGdc = results[5].totalGdc;
      this.computeRoa();
      this.queriesDone = true;
      this.screenFourCanContinue = true;
    }
...
```

I'm replacing specific properties but I also tested replacing the entire object reassigning the entire object, but it never notify or change the value of the binding objects in the child views.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Is it possible you have OnPush specified somewhere in this component hierarchy? That may limit the amount of updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help, we realized that the problem was mainly because we didn't realized that the object was override with an object that came from the database and also I'm using now

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // ...
  }
```

To update based on nested objects.